# Java Queue.This program result is empty.

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I am learning the Queue Data structure.I want to create Queue with linked list.I want to program ouput : 10 20
Program output: Queue empty  -1  Queue empty  -1

Where am I making mistakes?

The code is as given below:

```
class Node {
  int x;
  Node next;

  Node (int x){
    this.x=x;
    next=null;

}

}

public class QueQueLinked {
 static Node root=null;
 static Node latest=null;

 public static void enque(int x){
    if(root==null){
        Node root=new Node(x);
        root.x=x;
        root.next=null;
        latest=root;
    }

    else{
        latest.next=new Node(x);
        latest=latest.next;
        latest.next=null;


    }

}

public static int deque(){
    if(root==null){
        System.out.println("Queque empty");
        return -1;

    }
    int value=root.x;
    root=root.next;

    return value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   enque(10);
   enque(20);

    System.out.println(deque());
    System.out.println(deque());
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your root variable. You need to do:

```
public static void enque(int x){
    if(root==null){
        root=new Node(x);
        root.x=x;
        root.next=null;
        latest=root;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in this line:

```
Node root=new Node(x);
```

You are creating a new **local** variable named `root` that hides the the static **field** `root`. Instead you should write:

```
root=new Node(x);
```

If you have a local variable `root` that hides the static field `root` you could also access the static field by prepending it with your class name:

```
QueQueLinked.root = new Node(x)
```

In this case, however, you should rethink your variable names.